# How can I remove / delete a dynamically generated button in Android?

Tags: android, button, dynamically-generated

So I generated some button. The numbers it depends on the user (when clicked a button, create a new one).

This is how I made it:

```
   RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutcprompt);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams OBJ = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (140,80);
    if ((commandsi%6)==0) {adjust=adjust+86; commandsi=1;}
    OBJ.leftMargin =(140*(commandsi-1))+10;
    OBJ.topMargin =250+adjust;
    Button command = new Button(this);
    command.setLayoutParams(OBJ);
    command.setId(ID);
    command.setText(edittxt.getText().toString());
    edittxt.setText("");
    command.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.costum_button);
    command.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    command.setTextSize(14);
    layout.addView(command);
    command.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Button b = (Button)view;
            scommand=b.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    command.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I want to remove/delete them, but I don't know how.... I gave them a unique id, but I still dunno how can I remove them :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot comment another post, but using

```
command = new Button(this)
```

might involve an implicit memory Leak on `this`! (which can be the `Activity`). Rather use `Context` object. Or remove the button at least.

Then because you have the parent of your `Button`. Just remove it:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layoutcprompt);
View command = layout.findViewById(ID);
layout.removeView(command);
```

Comment: Great :) Thanks, that was the one ;) I made a while cycle to remove them and it's work. I modified your answer because first have to cast view to button.

Comment: I edited my answer, because there is no need to cast (excepting the parent...)

Answer (score 2):

Make command a global variable. Then you can access it later, and call `command.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

So at the top, of your class file, you would declare the global variable:

```
Button command;
```

Then remove the redefinition later on and instead assign to the global variable:

```
command = new Button(this);
```

Then when you want to hide it, call:

```
command.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: This method call a null pointer exception.
 If the user want to make 20 button and I create one global variable, and I don't call the "new Button(this);" how can I reach my goal?
I need a lot button I don't know how many, and all of them with unique text in it with unique id. I can create them, but I don't know how can I delete them... And the GONE method is not good, because I will make new buttons after that,(the numbers depend the user also)

Comment: Try instead, assigning them a dynamic id. then find the view by id, and remove. You would need to store the Ids in a list. Or  just store the globals button definitions in a list

Comment: yeah I just did it. I gave them a dynamic ID-s and I stored the last, so I knew every second all the ID-s.
Find the views by ID-s and remove them in a while cycle and done.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the documentation, 5 seconds of research can lead you to the [RemoveView method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29).

```
layout.removeView(command);
```

**Update**

If you have a null pointer exception on this line, means your `layout` is null, not your `command`. Make your `layout` variable global for that class.

Also be sure to keep different variables for each of your created buttons. If you have a global variable, and create 10 buttons using the same variable you will only have a reference to the last one created. If you explain exactly when you want to remove the button we might be able to help you further.

As an example, if you want to remove the button when the user clicks on it you can change your clickListener:

```
command.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Button b = (Button)view;
            scommand=b.getText().toString();
            layout.removeView(view);    
    }
    });
```

Comment: yeah I Know I tried...
NullPointerException, I made a command Global variable: "Button command;" And I made this line before I call the removeView: "if (command != null) layout.removeView(command);" but still nullpointerexception...

Answer (score 1):

One other implementation that may help others who view this thread is that you can consider removing all the child elements in the parent layout. Once you get the view's parent (which I assume is a layout container),you can remove all the child elements.

```
command.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)view.getParent();
            vg.removeAllViews();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this for security purpose:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) command.getParent();
if(null!=layout) //for safety only  as you are doing onClick
layout.removeView(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this snipper

For Adding the Button

```
        LinearLayout dynamicview = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams  lprams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setId(count);
            final int id_ = btn.getId();
            btn.setText("Capture Image" + id_);
            btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 80, 90));
            dynamicview.addView(btn, lprams);
            btn = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

For removing the button

```
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
            View command = layout.findViewById(count);
            layout.removeView(command);
```